# How to find the sum of the amount per Month, Quarter and YTD in current -1 year?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table which contains two columns: date and amount.

[image]

I want to calculate sum of amount per month in current -1 year, like below:

[image]

Please help me in the same.

Comment: @NikhilB Please don't use comments to write an answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use CTE in MySQL to generate amount of the same month as last year. you can use this as reference

```
WITH sum_last as ( 
select sum(amount) as amount,
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 year)) as monthyear 
from test 
WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 year) 
group by EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 year)) ) 
select t.date,t.amount,sum_last.amount from test t left join sum_last on EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM date) = sum_last.monthyear;
```